# create rotated ribbons in css

Tags: css

how can i create a ribbon like [this](http://i49.tinypic.com/308e05y.png) that sits on corner of my boxes and it is rotated too with css and without images.

i know that exits some tools and tutorials like [this](http://www.css3d.net/ribbon-generator/) and [this](http://css3-tutorial.com/creating-ribbons-in-css3) that makes ribbons easily with css.
but all of those are horizontal type while i want to create a rotated one.

Comment: That particular example is probably just a partially tranaparent picture that they put on top of the content.

Comment: @MrLister - I guess ahmad decided to mark answers as accepted after looking at my comment. It was 25% when I saw it.

Comment: yes it is a picture. but can we create a similar sample of that only with css

Comment: @ahmad: Just use one of the tools you've mentioned in the question and rotate them yourself.. `transform: rotate(45deg);`

Comment: @ahmad You better try making one of your own. Examples are given how to do it. No one is going to spoon feed you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you follow those tutorials to create a horizontal ribbon, use CSS3 Transform (Rotation) to rotate the ribbon: http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/R6jMH/ Have a look

Comment: thanks. i know **transform** css property and that how it works. but when i want use of it with a horizontal ribbons to rotate it , the result will not similar to one that i showed.

Comment: the link which you given in http://css3-tutorial.com/creating-ribbons-in-css3 this one just add this transformer in it