# Ribbon for Bootstrap Table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-shapes

I am searching for the way and asking how to make this kind a ribbon in mine table. I need to make it to look's like this[image: table picture].

I have 0 experiences whit ribbons, found some solution how to make them, and they are very nice, but I do not know how to wrap it around mine table.

I would like from someone to explain to me how to make this wright, so I can learn something out of this, because I need to put another ribbon in mine navigation bar.

```html
<!-- Tables
      ================================================== -->
    <div class="table">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div class="bs-component"><!--Start the table-->
                <table class="table table-striped" data-scrollreveal="enter left, wait 1.5s">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th><h1>Start Ribbon Here!<h1></th>
                      <th>Mine Picture Here</th>
                      <th>Mine Picture Here</th>
                      <th>Mine Picture Here</th>
                      <th>Mine Picture Here</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr class="active">
                      <td>Membership Plan</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                      <td>Membership Plan</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                      <td>Membership Plan</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                      <td>Membership Plan</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                      <td>Membership Plan</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                    </tr><tr class="active">
                      <td><h1>Ribbon End Here!</h1></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
                      
                    
                  </tbody>
                </table> 
              </div><!-- end of table -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Mine [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/p4tbv6cq/) table example.

Comment: Could you provide us with the resources you plan to wrap around that table?

Comment: @Alexander Johansen, you have mine table fiddle link up here, and I have found this answer helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167942/create-rotated-ribbons-in-css, but I am having truble wrap it around in mine table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pseudo elements on your parent div element.

Something like:

[This fiddle shows](https://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/p4tbv6cq/1/)

Or this snippet:

```css
.table {
  position: relative;
}
.table:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  background: teal;
  border-left: 5px dashed blue;
  border-right: 5px dashed blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px teal,  inset 0 5px 5px -2px lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 2px 2px;
}
.table:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  left: 40px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background: teal;
  border-bottom: 5px dashed blue;
  border-right: 5px dashed blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px teal;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<!-- Tables
      ================================================== -->
<div class="table">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <div class="bs-component">
          <!--Start the table-->
          <table class="table table-striped" data-scrollreveal="enter left, wait 1.5s">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <h1>Start Ribbon Here!<h1></th>
                      <th>Mine Picture Here</th>
                      <th>Mine Picture Here</th>
                      <th>Mine Picture Here</th>
                      <th>Mine Picture Here</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr class="active">
                      <td>Membership Plan</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                      <td>Membership Plan</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                      <td>Membership Plan</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                      <td>Membership Plan</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                      <td>Membership Plan</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                      <td>Column content</td>
                    </tr><tr class="active">
                      <td><h1>Ribbon End Here!</h1>
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
              </tr>


              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- end of table -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could then use a negative z-index to position the banner below the text.

Comment: I will check it as soon as possible, not at mine lap top atm, and thank you.

Comment: @Idiomatic: no problem. It should at least give you an understanding of how it's works, anyway :)

Comment: I have combine it whit hover and z-index and it is locking lovely, this was helpful, thank you once again.